# Как правильно сделать удаление ячейки в collectionView?

Tags: swift, swift4

Подскажите, плз! 
Как при нажатие кнопки, которая вылезает за пределы ячейки обратиться к ячейки? Фишка заключается в том, что у меня ещё один жест повешен на view, чтобы при нажатие на любое место телефона убрать редактирование ячейки. То есть если нажать на кнопку за пределами ячейки, то кнопка не сработает, а сработает жест, который на view.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я попробовал с помощью определение координаты нажатие. Но тогда, опять часть кнопки, которая за пределом ячейки не сработает.

```
@objc func deleteImageTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let point = sender.location(in: collectionView)
    if let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: point) {
        deleteCategory(indexPath: indexPath, context: context)
        isDelete = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вместо тапа на View использовать атрибут collectionView:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]